# How to get grouped product prices in product tab?

Tags: php, xml, magento, layout, product

I'm actually trying to move the grouped products prices information (which contains name/price/quantity for each of the products grouped into the current product displayed) in the product page, from the main area close to the product image, into the first modern tab which is named after tarifs.

My first tab "tarifs" usually calls a file `/catalog/product/view/relatedsaph.phtml`.

What i'm doing is:

I move the PHP call which currently displays this information:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data');
```

from the `/catalog/product/view.phtml` to my file `/catalog/product/view/relatedsaph.phtml`

Then i try to change the reference name in `catalog.xml` from

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Grouped)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_grouped" name="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.grouped.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
```

to

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Grouped)</label>
    <reference name="product.info.tabs">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_grouped" name="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.grouped.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
```

I'm changing the reference name where the call is awaited to the value given for the "tabs" zone in the `catalog.xml` layout file, or else the same I copy paste the modified XML code with the modified reference into my `local.xml` file but nothing happens, the information isn't displayed anymore... and nothing appears into my tab...

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Finally it came through the night (how weird i always get my answers during my sleep only when i dare to ask them, did struggle about that for days and it's only now i ask i have the answer, nevertheless...)

The first tab, in the

```
catalog.xml
```

file is defined as follows :

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog"><alias>rates</alias><title>Rates</title><block>catalog/product_list_relatedsaph</block><template>catalog/product/list/relatedsaph.phtml</template></action>
```

in fact the issue was i didn't know i could use the "ALIAS" tag content as reference for the block i'm willing to move so the declaration in local.xml :

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Grouped)</label>
    <reference name="rates">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_grouped" name="product.info.grouped" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.grouped.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
```

and here it works (thank you all anyway :-)